# Getting an error "Cause: AMQ119031: Unable to validate user" in Spring-Boot app

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-jms, jboss-eap-7, activemq-artemis

I'm getting the following error when trying to connect to ActiveMQ Artemis Queue deployed on JBoss EAP 7.1.

> Error: DefaultMessageListenerContainer: Could not refresh JMS
>   Connection for destination 'jms/queue/QueueA' - retrying using
>   FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=139,
>   maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: AMQ119031: Unable to validate user

Here is the code I'm using:

```
@Bean public DefaultMessageListenerContainer myFactory() throws NamingException { 
   DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
   listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(getConnectionFactory());
   listenerContainer.setDestinationName("jms/queue/QueueA");
   listenerContainer.setMessageListener(new MessageReceiver());
   return listenerContainer; 
}

private ConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory() throws NamingException { 
   final Properties env = new Properties();
   env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory); 
   env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:8080"); 
   env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "Username"); 
   env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "Password"); 
   InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(env); 
   return (ConnectionFactory) ic.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code and/or configuration where you're using the DefaultMessageListenerContainer?

Comment: @Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer myFactory() throws NamingException {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();

        listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(getConnectionFactory());
        listenerContainer.setDestinationName("jms/queue/QueueA");
        listenerContainer.setMessageListener(new MessageReceiver());
        return listenerContainer;
    }

Comment: private ConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory() throws NamingException {
        final Properties env = new Properties();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory);
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:8080");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "Username");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "Password");
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(env);
        return (ConnectionFactory) ic.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
    }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message (i.e. `AMQ119031: Unable to validate user`) indicates, you have not provided the proper credentials when creating your JMS connection.

The username & password information you've provided in the properties for your JNDI lookup apply **only** for the JNDI lookup (i.e. *not* for the JMS connection). JNDI and JMS are 100% independent of each other.

You must configure the appropriate Spring component with your JMS username and password so it can be used when it invokes [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(String,String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/ConnectionFactory.html#createConnection-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) or [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory.createContext(String,String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/ConnectionFactory.html#createContext-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). Try returning an instance of [`UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/connection/UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.html) from your `getConnectionFactory()` method.

Comment: Can you help me figure out how and which Spring component have to configured with the username and password. I haven't come through any article that does that in Spring(creating a connection,context)

Comment: Thank You Justin. I was successfully able to connect and read messages from Queue.Below is my modified getConnectionFactory()

Comment: Addition to code of getConnectionFactory in the post:                 
 ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) ic.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
 UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter = new UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter();
 userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setUsername("Username");
 userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setPassword("Password");
 userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setTargetConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
 return userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter;